# causal perturbation theory and counter-terms in renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory

Is there an analogue for the counter-terms used in renormalization methods in causal perturbation theory? Or does it have no use for counter-term-like items at all in its mathematics?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/paqft-idea-references/